# Quantifier Statements

Tags: logic

> $\exists x\forall y, \exists z \ni xz=y$.
>
> $\forall x, \forall y, \exists z \ni z>y \implies z>x+y$.

Other than testing lots of values, is there a way to determine if the above two statements are true in general?

Hints preferable over answers please.

Edit: $x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}.$

Comment: What is the domain of discourse over which $x,y$, and $z$ range?

Comment: The real numbers; I have edited that information into the question now.

Comment: How would testing lots of values determine general truth?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, I meant testing values until one fails, which would give me a counterexample. (However, I'm not sure how to determine if something is true or false in general in the first place.)

Comment: You are asking for a very special case of [quantifier elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field#Model_Theory:_decidability_and_quantifier_elimination). The general problem is decidable, but its complexity is very high.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

- For the first one, note that $x=0$ definitely doesn’t work, but if $x\ne 0$ the statement $xz=y$ is just $z=\frac{y}x$.
- For the second, note that an implication is vacuously true if its antecedent is false.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to start on the inside and reduce the number of variables and quantifiers.  For example, for the first problem, $(\exists z)(xz=y)$ is equivalent to 
$x \neq 0 \vee y = 0$.  That gives you $(\exists x)(\forall y)(x \neq 0 \vee y = 0)$.  This may be obvious, but let's continue the same way and consider $(\forall y)(x \neq 0 \vee y = 0)$.  This is equivalent to $x\neq 0$.  So the original statement is equivalent to $(\exists x)(x \neq 0)$, which is obviously true (take $x = 1$).

Sorry, I guess this answers the entire first problem when you just wanted a hint, but this is a tool you can apply to other problems.